VertX OAuth2 Extend HTTP Header
Our OAuth2 Server has the possibility to handle OpenTelemetry TraceId. Is there a way to inject a traceID into the VertX OAuth2 Handler?
Currently we see the incoming request, long nothing (Oauth2 request/answer) and the post login processing. It would be nice, if we can fill this hole with the oauth2 server span.
A workaround will be a child span-start before oauth2.authenticate and span-end at on-Complete.
